# Allow anyone to downvote un-relevant tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Id like to recommend users below 2000 points to be able to down-vote new un-relevant tags , i personally have come across a tag which is completely un-relevant as it refers to an amount in ksh ie `ksh93`  the tag link in question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksh93 .

Comment: What do you mean by a tag down vote?

Comment: What's wrong with the [ksh93] tag? What does "an amount in ksh" means? You know the tag refers to [KornShell 93](http://www.kornshell.com/doc/ksh93.html), right?

Comment: @Yannis [ksh93]  is something like [us93]where us= usa dollars

Comment: Oh, my. The tag is **not** about the Kenyan shilling.

Comment: @NathanOliver i mean review the tag to removed as the tag is un-relevant

Comment: @Yannis Yes the tag is not about [ksh]  which already exists its a tag on denomination / amount in kenyashillings

Comment: Rep is mostly about limiting access to sharp-edged moderator tools.  Kinda important when users don't yet know that you can't DV a tag.  Fwiw, 93 is the version number, appending a version to a tag is a pretty common practice.

Comment: Just wondering why the downvote ?

Comment: The tag is about the 1993 version of KornShell. It has nothing to do with shillings, Kenyan or otherwise.

Comment: So let me make sure I understand this:  You want to take the least experienced users on the site and have them review a tool that they likely don't fully understand what it's used for.  And at the same time, you're requesting a brand new review and voting mechanism that doesn't exist yet.  And what benefit do you think this would bring the site?

Comment: How is it that you think `[ksh93]` refers to Kenyan shillings, but `[ksh]` does not?

Comment: If the tag creator would have written a wiki / something about it then this would resolve further disputes !

Comment: Not  least experienced users but atleast  , minimize the score rating to something like 500 or 1 gold badge , from the 2000 score points !

Comment: Jimmy - The privilege levels are there in part to help prevent new users from actively harming the site.  Your suggestion would cause a lot more harm than good as it's clearly based upon a misunderstanding of what that tag and tags in general are meant for.

Comment: All the same , this was a question to suggest , which i guess thats what stackoverflow is about and not un-necessary downvotes  , which most user  i have come to learn do , @GlenH7 and others , thanks for the clarifications

Answer (score 15):

You can suggest an edit to remove the tag, in the same way you can suggest an edit to the body of the question.

If the edit reviewers agree the tag will be removed.

However, please be 100% sure you know what the tag actually refers to and what the question is about before making such suggestions. If you get it wrong and make a lot of bad suggestions your ability to make suggested edits may well be removed.

Comment: @ChrissF how would i suggest to remove the tag ?

Comment: @jimmyobonyo click edit on the question and then remove the tag from the tags box.

Comment: Thanks this resolves it